# django rest-framework : can't get static files

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I use rest-framework in my localhost it works well :

[image]

But when I put my code to amazon EC2 and use supervisor open the `port 8000`  with `wsgi.ini`
BUT it can't get CSS and JS files:

```
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://ec2-1-2-3-4.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css"
```

my settings.py :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ("js", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'js')),
    ("css", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'css')),
    ("images", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'images')),
    ("fonts", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'fonts')),
)
```

Why would this happen??
Please help me! Thank you very much

Comment: Can we see your settings for staticfiles?

Comment: did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Thank you @RobAgar ,manage.py collectstatic works well!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

run `manage.py collectstatic` :)